# Cyclic covers which are hypersurfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a $m$-fold cyclic cover $X$ of the complex projective space $P^n$ branched a along a smooth hypersurface of degree $m$. Then $X$ is smooth as well. Is $X$ then a degree $m$ hypersurface in $P^{n+1}$?

Locally $X$ is given by the zero locus of a polynomial $z^m=F(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ where $F$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. That is the reason I have this doubt.

Is it true when $m=n$? That is if $X$ is a degree $n$ cyclic cover of $P^n$ branched over a degree $n$ smooth hypersurface, then is $X$ a hypersurface in $P^{n+1}$?

Comment: This is always true (no compatibility between $n$ and $m$ is required).

Comment: If we take a degree three cover $X$ of $P^2$ branched along a cubic curve, is it a cubic surface in $P^3$? I saw somewhere that a cubic surface in $P^3$ is a degree three cover of $P^2$ branched over a sextic?

Comment: Yes, a degree 3 cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$ branched along a cubic curve is a cubic surface.

Comment: @Sasha, the reason I had this doubt is as follows. A cubic surface has canonical bundle $O_{P^3}(-1)|_X$ whose self intersection is 3. Whereas if we take a triple cover of $p:Y\rightarrow P^2$ branched over a cubic, then the canonical class of $Y$ is $p^*O(-2)$ whose self intersection is 12. So how can $X$ and $Y$ be the same?

Comment: The canonical class of a triple covering is $p^*\mathcal{O}(-1)$.

Comment: @sasha, thank you I just realised that.